# Best Azure AD Solution to automatically Sync Users/Groups from one Azure AD Tenant to another

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-identity

Looking for ideal solution in Azure AD to automatically sync users between two Azure AD Tenants
The scenario i'm looking for is as follows

- Corporate and our business project has separate Azure AD Tenants
- Want to leverage Corp Azure AD to sync internal users directly to my projects Azure AD to avoid onboarding all new ppl into the company
- When some internal employee leaves, sync off-boarding as well so that if Corp removes someone from Azure AD, it gets removed from my Projects AD as well

What are the best options for me ?

- Azure B2B sync using external identities
- Azure Lighthouse
- Others ?
- Can users be automatically synced without them requiring to click some activation/invitation link in emails ? Can this be fully automated without "invite link emails " etc ?

Looking for some assistance

Answer (score 0):

**AADConnect**(AzureAD connect) can synchronize the same users, groups, and contacts from a single Active Directory to multiple Azure AD tenants.
These tenants can be in different Azure environments.

You will need to deploy an AADConnect server for every Azure AD tenant you want to synchronize to.
Note: One AADConnect server can synchronize to not more than one Azure AD tenant.

**Reference**:[sync ad objects to multiple azure ad tenants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-topologies#sync-ad-objects-to-multiple-azure-ad-tenants)

Also see [use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups)

Comment: Isn't AD Connect used to sync between AD On-Prem and Azure AD ?